# Include a lib in Rails model - Is "require" required or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, require

I have a model that right now looks like this:

```
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageManipulation
  ...
end
```

`ImageManipulation` is a library named `image_manipulation.rb`, located in `/lib/`  I could work with the model without any problems, but today I had to do some manipulations through the rails console, and when trying to do `Logo.delete_all`, I got this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Logo::ImageManipulation
```

So, I change my model to look like this:

```
require 'image_manipulation'
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageManipulation
  ...
end
```

My question is... Why is the require necessary when I want to work with the Logo model in the rails console, but is not necessary when launching `rails s` and manipulating the model through my application?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your autoload settings.

When you load up the Rails console, Rails won't immediately `require` every file in your app, because this would take a long time. Instead it uses "lazy loading" - it doesn't load a class into memory until it actually needs it.

The way this works is that, when you use a constant (i.e. a class or a module) in your code that the interpreter hasn't seen yet, it will make an intelligent guess about which file it needs to load to find the code for that constant. E.g. for `User` it will look for a file called `user.rb`, for `ImageManipulation` it will look for `image_manipulation.rb`, and for a namespaced constant e.g. `Image::Manipulation` it will look for `image/manipulation.rb`.

Where does it look for these files? In your "autoload paths", which is a list of directories stored in the `config` settings of your Rails app. So for the file `user.rb` it will look for `app/models/user.rb`, `app/controllers/user.rb`, `app/helpers/user.rb` etc until a) it finds a file and loads it or b) it runs out of places to look, in which case it will raise a `NameError`.

So there are two cases where you need to `require` a file explicitly:

1. `ImageManipulation` is defined in a file whose name Rails can't figure out automatically (i.e. a file called `image_manipulation.rb`.)
2. `image_manipulation.rb` isn't in a directory that's in your autoload paths.

By default, your `autoload_paths` includes all the standard `app` directories like `models` and `controllers`, but does **not** include `lib` (as far I'm aware... it may depend on your version of Rails). So if you want to be able to autoload `ImageManipulation` you should put it somewhere it can be autoloaded, or add `lib` to your autoload paths by adding the following line to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths.push(Rails.root.join("lib"))
```

I don't know why `ImageManipulation` is being autoloaded under `rails s` but not under `rails c`, but I'd suspect that you're running the two rails commands under different environments (e.g. one in development mode and the other in production), and the environments have different autoload settings. Try searching your app directory for `autoload` or `autoload_paths` and seeing if you can spot anything unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that `rails s` is starting things in development mode and autoloading classes found in your library locations. When running the app via `rails console`, this autoloading may not be happening to the same degree.